# How does Excel evaluate FACT(170)/FACT(169) correctly?

Tags: excel, floating-point, floating-point-precision

170! approaches the limit of a floating point double: 171! will overflow.

However 170! is over 300 digits long.

There is, therefore, **no way** that 170! can be represented precisely in floating point.

Yet Excel returns the correct answer for 170! / 169!.

Why is this? I'd expect some error to creep in, but it returns an integral value. Does Excel somehow know how to optimise this calculation?

Comment: See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/78113 for cases where Excel does not adhere to the IEEE 754 specification it implements.

Comment: The “therefore” in your question is dubious (although the conclusion is correct). 10^22 is 23 digits long, so by the same reasoning there should be **no way** that it can be represented precisely in binary64, yet it can. 170! both has a lot of digits and cannot be represented precisely in binary64 though.

Comment: @PascalCuoq Yep, 170! requires a significand of (170 factorial highBit - 170 factorial lowBit + 1) -> 854 bits. It's funny that your 10^22 example is the last representable power of ten in double precision, because 22! is also the last representable factorial (2 to: 170) detect: [:n | n factorial asFloat  ~= n factorial] -> 23

Comment: I would very much expect `FACT(x)/FACT(y)` to be optimized for `y<=x`. The reason is that this expression appears in frequently in statistics .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you find the closest `double`s to 170! and 169!, they are

```
double oneseventy = 5818033100654137.0 * 256;
double onesixtynine = 8761273375102700.0;
```

times the same power of two.  The closest `double` to the quotient of these is exactly 170.0.

Also, Excel may compute 170! by multiplying 169! by 170.

William Kahan has a paper called "[How Futile are Mindless Assessments of Roundoff in Floating-Point Computation?](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~wkahan/Mindless.pdf)" where he discusses some of the insanity that goes on in Excel.  It may be that Excel is not computing 170 exactly, but rather it's hiding an ulp of reality from you.

Comment: @YogiBear: Maple gives me `169! / 2^1012 * 2^53 ~= 8761273375102700.341917118244573688`.   I'm pretty sure it's right.

Comment: @PascalCuoq: For whatever reason, I've only heard people call him "Bill Kahan."  It appears he's called "William Kahan" wherever his name is written, though.

Comment: I have heard people call him “William” or “Velvel”, but “Bill” is a new one to me. It wouldn't make sense to let people anglicize the name to William (which doesn't even look like “Velvel”) and then change the pseudonym to “Bill”.

Comment: I quite like the irony of spelling anglicise "anglicize".

Answer (score 2):

The answer of tmyklebu is already perfect. But I wanted to know more.
What if implementation of n! was something trivial as `return double(n)*(n-1)!`...

Here is a Smalltalk snippet, but you can translate in many other languages, that's not the point:

```
(2 to: 170) count: [:n | 
    | num den |
    den := (2 to: n - 1) inject: 1.0 into: [:p :e | p*e].
    num := n*den.
    num / den ~= n].
```

And the answer is `12`

So you have not been particulary lucky, due to good properties of round to nearest even rounding mode, out of these 169 numbers, only 12 don't behave as expected.
Which ones? Replace `count:` by `select:` and you get:
`#(24 47 59 61 81 96 101 104 105 114 122 146)`

If I had an Excel handy, I would ask to evaluate 146!/145!.

Curiously (only apparently curiously), a less naive solution that computes the exact factorial with large integer arithmetic, then convert to nearest float, does not perform better !

```
(2 to: 170) reject: [:n | 
    n factorial asFloat / (n-1) factorial asFloat = n]
```

leads to:

```
#(24 31 34 40 41 45 46 57 61 70 75 78 79 86 88 92 93 111 115 116 117 119 122 124 141 144 147 164)
```

Comment: I am not surprised that the correctly rounded factorial behaves worse. As tmyklebu alluded to, with the naive method, assuming multiplications are ordered from small to large factors, !170 is computed by multiplying 170 with the result of the very same computation that is used for !169. The question is similar to whether `d1 * d2 / d2` is `d1` in floating-point arithmetic, with `d1` a double` and `d2` a double (with few digits set in the significand, which helps in some cases). With correctly rounded factorial, you have instead d1 = round_to_double(r1), d2 = round_to_double(r2), r2/r1=170.